# Binary operator as exponent

Tags: math-operators

I've defined

```
\newcommand{\skw}{\mathbin{\star}}
```

which works as expected in expressions like `$a\star b$`. However, unlike `$a^+$`, when I try `$a^\skw$`, I get a compilation error, which goes away if I bother to write `$a^{\skw}$` instead. So my question is how should I define `\skw` to be able to simply write `$a^\skw$`?

Comment: the form without braces is not supported (for any superscript) in latex. It sometimes works but as you see you can't rely on it.

Comment: you could however just use `^\star` as that is already `\mathbin` with its default definition, declared by `\DeclareMathSymbol{\star}{\mathbin}{letters}{"3F}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The form without braces is not supported (for any superscript) in latex. It sometimes works but as you see you can't rely on it.

You could however just use `^\star` as that is already `\mathbin` with its default definition, declared by `\DeclareMathSymbol{\star}{\mathbin}{letters}{"3F}`

Technically you can omit the braces if the superscript expands to a single unexpandable token or brace group (with the latter always acting as `\mathord`).

so `^\star` works as it is a `\mathchardef` token with mathbin spacing.
`\newcommand{\skw}{{\mathbin{\star}}}` would also work in the superscript but the braces would force `\mathord` spacing.

If you want a version of `\star` with a different `\mathclass` then rather than defining say

```
\newcommand{\skw}{\mathrel{\star}}
```

you could use

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\skw}{\mathrel}{letters}{"3F}
```

to make a `\mathrel` token.

But however you define it you should *always*  brace superscripts within the document markup rather than rely on the low level parsing that `^` does which is completely unlike macro arguments,

```
\newcommand\foo{abc}... $x^\foo$
```

gives no error but gives `$x^{a}  b c$`  which is almost never what is wanted.

If you omit braces you get an error or not and if you get no error you get sensible output or not at the mercy of the internal implementation details of the token used. The behaviour is well defined, but best avoided.

Answer (score 4):

I show what we can do with this problem in OpTeX. When exponent begins with `\mathbin` or `\mathrel` or `\mathop` (after first expansion) then this primitive command is simply ignored. Something similar should be done with subscript.

```
\catcode`\^13 \def^{\sp\ea\testnext}
\catcode`\^=12
\mathcode`\^="8000

\def\testnext{\immediateassignment\futurelet\next\testnextA}
\def\testnextA{\casesof\next
  \mathbin {\ignoreit}
  \mathrel {\ignoreit}
  \mathop  {\ignoreit}
  \_finc {}%
}

\def\skw{\mathrel{\star\star}}
$
 a \skw b^\skw
$
\bye
```